# Convert TimeZone of Date in RequestBody of retrofit

Tags: android, date, datetime, timezone, gson

I'm using retrofit for making calls to server, I have requestBody like this:

```
class MyRequestBody {
String id;
Date date;
}
```

I want to convert timezone of date object in requestBody.

I tried these things:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz")
.create();

Retrofit.Builder adapterBuilder = new Retrofit
.Builder()
.baseUrl(baseUrl)
.addConverterFactory(GsonCustomConverterFactory.create(gson))

class GsonCustomConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory
{
    public static GsonCustomConverterFactory create(Gson gson) {
        return new GsonCustomConverterFactory(gson);
    }

    private final Gson gson;
    private final GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory;

    private GsonCustomConverterFactory(Gson gson) {
        if (gson == null) throw new NullPointerException("gson == null");
        this.gson = gson;
        this.gsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if(type.equals(String.class))
            return new GsonResponseBodyConverterToString<Object>(gson, type);
        else
            return gsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return gsonConverterFactory.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, retrofit);
    }
}
```

but above code can only control the pattern of date not timezone.
I want to change timezone also.
Thanks!

Comment: Why use `Date`? I don’t know how Gson handles the types from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), but I do know that `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated. So avoid if you can.

Comment: I can't avoid Date for now, I want proper Date converter with timezone

Comment: Which time zone do you want? Asking because the `Date` cannot have a time zone. Your string can, of course.

Comment: in GMT/UTC timezone

Comment: TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5"));This will change hole application timezone.

Comment: @KintanPatel I don't want to change entire application timezone, I want GMT timezone only when I'm sending request to server. My application should be in local timezone only

Comment: can you show a sample String of date you get from server?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir I'm getting date as long from server like this: 1575287564000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution for my question.
I used `TypeAdapter`.

```
class DateConverter extends TypeAdapter<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Date date) throws IOException {
        if (date == null) {
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            out.value(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
        }
    }
}
```

Then setting this Adapter to Gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateConverter())
                .create();

Retrofit.Builder adapterBuilder = new Retrofit
.Builder()
.baseUrl(baseUrl)
.addConverterFactory(GsonCustomConverterFactory.create(gson))
```

Thanks for the help in comment

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. I understand that you cannot avoid it for now. Probably you got a `Date` from a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is worse, it’s a notorious troublemaker. And you *can* avoid this one.

```
class DateConverter extends TypeAdapter<Date> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Date date) throws IOException {
        if (date == null) {
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            String dateTimeString = date.toInstant()
                    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
            out.value(dateTimeString);
        }
    }
}
```

java.time even has a built-in formatter for the format you are writing. So there’s no need to write our own format pattern string, which is good because it’s always an error-prone task. I also like the fact that the conversion to UTC is explicit in the code. It’s clearer to the reader what happens.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.